# In a UID namespace, can I setuid to an unmapped UID?

Tags: linux-kernel, namespace

Suppose I'm user ID 1000. I run a program inside a UID namespace, mapping UID 0 inside the namespace to UID 1000 outside the namespace. The program then attempts to change its own UID to 50, which doesn't have a corresponding UID outside the namespace.

Does the program successfully change its own (kernel) UID? If so, what does its UID appear to be from outside the namespace? Is it still 1000, or is it something else?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I (finally) tested it in Fedora Rawhide. It looks like my initial impression is correct: if you run `seteuid(50)` inside a namespace, but uid 50 inside the namespace doesn't correspond to a uid outside the namespace, then the call to seteuid simply fails.

In here, I'll use "kernel uid" to refer to a process's uid as seen by the kernel (and most processes outside of the user namespace), and "subjective uid" to refer to a process's uid as seen by itself (and other processes inside the namespace).

### Test 1

First, let's see what happens when root calls `seteuid(50)`. We open up Python, and see what its pid is:

```
[fedora@ip-0-0-0-0 ~]$ sudo python                             
Python 2.7.6 (default, Feb  4 2014, 15:36:52)                         
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-14)] on linux2                     
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os                                                         
>>> os.getpid()                                                       
1081
```

In a second terminal, we can see that python's kernel uid is, in fact, 0 (root):

```
[fedora@ip-0-0-0-0 ~]$ ls -ld /proc/1081
dr-xr-xr-x. 9 root root 0 Feb  7 03:27 /proc/1081
```

And the subjective uid is, of course, 0 as well:

```
>>> os.geteuid()  
0
```

So now we change our uid to 50:

```
>>> os.seteuid(50)
```

In the second terminal, we see that the kernel uid has indeed changed to 50:

```
[fedora@ip-0-0-0-0 ~]$ ls -ld /proc/1081
dr-xr-xr-x. 9 50 root 0 Feb  7 03:27 /proc/1081
```

### Test 2

Okay, now let's use "unshare" to create a new user namespace.

```
[fedora@ip-0-0-0-0 ~]$ unshare --user python                   
Python 2.7.6 (default, Feb  4 2014, 15:36:52)                         
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-14)] on linux2                     
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os                                                         
>>> os.getpid()                                                       
1084
```

In the second terminal, we see that this process's kernel uid is 1000 (fedora):

```
[fedora@ip-0-0-0-0 ~]$ ls -ld /proc/1084
dr-xr-xr-x. 9 fedora fedora 0 Feb  7 03:30 /proc/1084
```

But in the first terminal, we see that its subjective uid is 65534 (not mapped):

```
>>> os.geteuid()
65534
```

So, in the second terminal, we give python a mapping:

```
[fedora@ip-0-0-0-0 ~]$ echo '0 1000 1' > /proc/1084/uid_map
```

In the first terminal, we see that python's subjective uid is now 0:

```
>>> os.geteuid()                     
0
```

We try to set python's uid to 50, but this fails with "Invalid argument" (presumably EINVAL), because the subjective uid 50 has no mapping to a kernel uid:

```
>>> os.seteuid(50)                   
Traceback (most recent call last):   
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

In the second terminal, we see that the process's kernel uid is unchanged:

```
[fedora@ip-0-0-0-0 ~]$ ls -ld /proc/1084
dr-xr-xr-x. 9 fedora fedora 0 Feb  7 03:30 /proc/1084
```

And in the first terminal, we see that the process's subjective uid is unchanged, too:

```
>>> os.geteuid()
0
```

### Test 3

Okay, what happens if we define a mapping containing multiple uids? According to the LWN.net article "[Namespaces in operation, part 5: User namespaces](http://lwn.net/Articles/532593/)", we need to run python *after* mapping the uids. (I tried this without mapping the uids before running python, and the seteuid operation gave "Operation not permitted".) So first, we run a shell in a second new user namespace:

```
[fedora@ip-0-0-0-0 ~]$ unshare --user  
id: cannot find name for user ID 65534        
id: cannot find name for group ID 65534       
id: cannot find name for user ID 65534        
[I have no name!@ip-10-239-133-144 ~]$ echo $$
1798
```

Then, in the second terminal, we need to be root in order to define the mapping:

```
[root@ip-10-239-133-144 fedora]# echo '0 1000 2' > /proc/1798/uid_map
```

According to the `whoami` command, our subjective uid is root now, so let's open up Python and set our subjective uid to 1:

```
[I have no name!@ip-0-0-0-0 ~]$ whoami                         
root                                                                  
[I have no name!@ip-0-0-0-0 ~]$ python                         
Python 2.7.6 (default, Feb  4 2014, 15:36:52)                         
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-14)] on linux2                     
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os                                                         
>>> os.seteuid(1)                                                     
>>> os.getpid()                                                       
1837
```

In the second terminal, we see that our kernel uid is now 1001, as expected:

```
[root@ip-10-239-133-144 fedora]# ls -ld /proc/1837
dr-xr-xr-x. 9 1001 fedora 0 Feb  7 04:00 /proc/1837
```

### Test 2 again?

In test 3, we needed to define the mapping before running Python in order for the call to seteuid() to succeed. In test 2, we didn't do this. So, the obvious question is, if we did define the mapping before running Python, would the call to seteuid() work? It turns out that the answer is no. First terminal:

```
[fedora@ip-0-0-0-0 ~]$ unshare --user  
id: cannot find name for user ID 65534        
id: cannot find name for group ID 65534       
id: cannot find name for user ID 65534        
[I have no name!@ip-0-0-0-0 ~]$ echo $$
1861
```

Second terminal:

```
[fedora@ip-0-0-0-0 ~]$ echo '0 1000 1' > /proc/1861/uid_map
```

First terminal:

```
[I have no name!@ip-0-0-0-0 ~]$ whoami                         
root                                                                  
[I have no name!@ip-0-0-0-0 ~]$ python                         
Python 2.7.6 (default, Feb  4 2014, 15:36:52)                         
[GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-14)] on linux2                     
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os                                                         
>>> os.geteuid()                                                      
0                                                                     
>>> os.seteuid(50)                                                    
Traceback (most recent call last):                                    
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                 
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

### Conclusion

In order for a call to seteuid within a user namespace to succeed, the uid passed to seteuid *must* have a mapping outside the user namespace. Otherwise, the call will fail with EINVAL.

Answer (score 3):

You need to define the translations after you've forked.

An excerpt from a fine article at LWN.net: "System calls that return process user and group IDs — for example, `getuid()` and `getgid()` — always return credentials as they appear inside the user namespace in which the calling process resides. If a user ID has no mapping inside the namespace, then system calls that return user IDs return the value defined in the file `/proc/sys/kernel/overflowuid`, which on a standard system defaults to the value 65534. Initially, a user namespace has no user ID mapping, so all user IDs inside the namespace map to this value. Likewise, a new user namespace has no mappings for group IDs, and all unmapped group IDs map to `/proc/sys/kernel/overflowgid` (which has the same default as `overflowuid`)."

Basically, once you've `clone(2)`'d off your progeny, you'll have the child's PID and be able to add to the tables in `/proc/CHILDPID/uid-map` and `/proc/CHILDPID/gid-map` to begin defining the translations.

As I understand the situation, if you run `seteuid(50)` inside your new namespace without a translation for it, you'll find that your euid is still 65534 until the translation is defined. As above, if there is no matching translation, `overflowuid`/`overflowgid` will be substituted.

The LWN.net article that explains most of the situation brilliantly is here: http://lwn.net/Articles/532593/

Comment: You say your euid will be "still 65534". Since the program is running as uid 1000, won't its euid be 1000 as seen from the outside, and 0 as seen from the inside? If I run `seteuid(50)`, according to you, it sounds like my euid will then be 65534 as seen from the outside. Will my euid be 50 as seen from the inside, as I'd expect?

Comment: I'm not fluent in kernelese, but for what it's worth, I looked at the Linux source code, and it looks like "default to 65534" is only the behavior for mapping a uid from outside a namespace into it. If you're trying to map a uid from *inside* a namespace *out* of it, the operation simply fails with `EINVAL`. So this makes it look like `seteuid(50)` will fail, since uid 50 as seen from the inside has no mapping outside the namespace.

Comment: I finally had the opportunity to test things, and it looks like this answer is incorrect. (Sorry if I'm beating a dead horse here.) If you run `seteuid(50)` without a matching substitution, `overflowuid` will not be substituted; instead, the call will fail with `EINVAL`.